# Sending mail with mailx and windows

Tags: windows, mailx, mks

I installed MKS ToolKit 8.5 in windows 7 and i want to send an email using mailx, i tried this in linux and works fine, but in Windows i dont have the same result. I'm trying send mail with a external smtp server. This is a command i used to sending mail from linux:

```
echo "This is a test..." | mailx -v -s "Test Email" -S smtp=my.server.smtp:25 -S from=test@test.cl me@gmail.com
```

I need this command in windows but can't yet run the right way of.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Exactly **HOW** is this not working?

Comment: i tried this on MKS TOOLKIT and this tool not recognize -v or -S options...

Comment: Trying to unixise windows, uh? Are you doing this in cygwin? Or on dos command prompt or in windows power shell? For each of those environments you could expect differing answers.

Comment: DOS command, adding /bin of mks toolkit on enviroments variables of windows.